# Google Cloud DNS setup mail

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

I have moved my DNS servers from GoDaddy to Google. Now I need to setup MX for mails.

I have done the following, and I can send mails but I do not get any mails. Do you know how to set it up?

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones/mydomainname
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Where would you post a question like this?

Comment: Quora, perhaps? Not here in any case. It's off-topic unless you've got some code you're working on that does this.

Comment: I thin it is ok as it is "Google's infrastructure." From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `*` from the DNS name.